# Accessing class instance variable from another class

Tags: ruby

I have this class in file "ghost.rb":

```
class Ghost
  attr_accessor :fragment

  def initialize(number_of_players)
    @fragment = ''
  end
end
```

I'm trying to access `@fragment` from another file in the same directory. Below is "aiplayer.rb" in the same directory.

```
require "./ghost"

class Aiplayer
  attr_reader :aiplayer

  def initialize
    @aiplayer = Player.new('AI Player')
  end

  def fragment_printer
    Ghost.fragment
  end
end
```

When I initialize an instance of `Aiplayer` and call the `fragment_printer` method on it, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `fragment' for Ghost:Class
from aiplayer.rb:17:in `fragment_printer'
```

I have the `attr_accessor` there, and so I'm not sure why I cannot reach the `fragment` variable from outside of the `Ghost` class. I'm having issues accessing class instance variables from outside of the class. Can anyone give me an explanation on this?

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of `Ghost`?

Comment: I haven't created an instance of Ghost. Do I need to do that before trying to access the fragment instance variable off of that?

Comment: After I type that, it seems like I need to do that as it's not a class variable?

Comment: How would I be able to connect the two together? I'm testing in Pry and create a new instance of Ghost and Aiplayer (x = Ghost.new, y = Aiplayer.new). How would I be able to modify the fragment_printer method to link to the Ghost fragment piece (which is constantly changing)?

Comment: That is an Instance instance variable. A class instance variable would look more like `class Ghost; class << self; attr_accessor :fragment; end; end;`

Comment: http://maximomussini.com/posts/ruby-class-variables/

Answer (score 1):

To link the instances you can pass the Ghost instance into the Aiplayer instance at initialization.

```
class Aiplayer
  attr_accessor :ghost

  def initialize(ghost_to_attach)
    self.ghost = ghost_to_attach
  end

  def fragment_printer
    ghost.fragment
  end

end

x = Ghost.new
y = Aiplayer.new(x)

x.fragment = 'foo'

y.fragment_printer
=> "foo"
```

This works because the object stored in variable `x` is the same object stored in the Aiplayer instance `ghost` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Steve, can you explain how ghost is being treated? Based off of "attr_accessor :ghost", is the attached instance of Ghost now an instance variable of the Aiplayer class?

Comment: yes, there's nothing magic about `attr_accessor :ghost` it's just a shortcut way of defining two instance methods... `def ghost; @ghost; end` and `def ghost=(new_value);@ghost = new_value;end` so the instance of ghost is stored in the instance variable `@ghost` of the `Aiplayer` instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone give me a quick explanation of this? I'm sure the explanation is simple, but I can't seem to find an answer as to why.

You wrote `Ghost.fragment` - it's not instance method, it's class method.

Class methods are not associated with object. You can read [about this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Ruby searches method `self.fragment` in `Ghost` class, but can't find it.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `fragment' for Ghost:Class
```

That's the reason of your problem.

Further depends on what you want. For example you can write `Ghost.new(5).fragment`. In this case `#fragment` is instance method that returns `@fragment`

I hope I could give you a sense.